# Iterating through TextBoxes in asp.net - why is this not working?

Tags: c#, asp.net, textbox

I have 2 methods I tried to iterate through all my textboxes in an asp.net page. The first is working, but the second one is not returning anything. Could someone please explain to me why the second one is not working?

This works ok:

```
List<string> list = new List<string>();

    foreach (Control c in Page.Controls)
    {
        foreach (Control childc in c.Controls)
        {
            if (childc is TextBox)
            {
                list.Add(((TextBox)childc).Text);
            }
        }
    }
```

and the "not working" code:

```
List<string> list = new List<string>();

    foreach (Control control in Controls)
    {
        TextBox textBox = control as TextBox;
        if (textBox != null)
        {
            list.Add(textBox.Text);
        }
    }
```

Comment: In the second lot of Code, does Controls even contain anything?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your first example is doing one level of recursion, so you're getting TextBoxes that are more than one control deep in the control tree. The second example only gets top-level TextBoxes (which you likely have few or none).

The key here is that the `Controls` collection is not every control on the page - rather, it is only the **immediate child controls** of the current control (and a `Page` is a type of `Control`). *Those* controls may in turn have child controls of their own. To learn more about this, read about the [ASP.NET Control Tree here](http://aspalliance.com/943) and about [NamingContainers here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.inamingcontainer.aspx). To truly get every TextBox anywhere on the page, you need a recursive method, like this:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> FindControls<T>(this Control control, bool recurse) where T : Control
{
    List<T> found = new List<T>();
    Action<Control> search = null;
    search = ctrl =>
        {
            foreach (Control child in ctrl.Controls)
            {
                if (typeof(T).IsAssignableFrom(child.GetType()))
                {
                    found.Add((T)child);
                }
                if (recurse)
                {
                    search(child);
                }
            }
        };
    search(control);
    return found;
}
```

Which is used as an [extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx), like so:

```
var allTextBoxes = this.Page.FindControls<TextBox>(true);
```

Comment: Ok, but what do you mean by top-level TextBoxes? My textboxes are just "normal" textboxes in a form..

Comment: @Svein see my updated answer. Your web form is a tree of controls - controls which contain controls which contain controls, and so on. "Top level" means controls that live at the very top, or outermost level, of the hierarchy.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed explanation and the code example! I love Stackoverflow, so many great people that want to help others :-)

Comment: Here is a link to another extension method that alls a method called All to a control collection which gives you an enumerable list of all controls contained in a control collection recursively.  http://extensionmethod.net/Details.aspx?ID=5
I find it quite handy sometimes.

Comment: Sorry I meant "adds a method" instead of "alls a method" :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to recurse. The controls are in a tree structure - `Page.Controls` is not a flattened list of all controls on the page. You'd need to do something like the following to get *all* values of TextBoxes:

```
void GetTextBoxValues(Control c, List<string> strings)
{
    TextBox t = c as TextBox;
    if (t != null)
        strings.Add(t.Text);

    foreach(Control child in c.Controls)
        GetTextBoxValues(child, strings);
}
```

...

```
List<string> strings = new List<string>();
GetTextBoxValues(Page, strings);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this piece of code to get list of all TextBoxes

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
   {

       public List<TextBox> ListOfTextBoxes = new List<TextBox>();
       protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
           // after execution this line
           FindTextBoxes(Page, ListOfTextBoxes);
           //ListOfTextBoxes will be populated with all text boxes with in the page.

       }


       private void FindTextBoxes(Control Parent, List<TextBox> ListOfTextBoxes)
       {
           foreach (Control c in Parent.Controls) {
               // if c is a parent control like panel
               if (c.HasControls())
               {
                   // search all control inside the panel
                   FindTextBoxes(c, ListOfTextBoxes);
               }
               else {
                   if (c is TextBox)
                   {
                       // if c is type of textbox then put it into the list
                       ListOfTextBoxes.Add(c as TextBox);
                   }
               }
           }
       }
   }
```

Comment: I have notified you before about linking to your own website without attribution.