# Finding page controls starting with some string

Tags: c#, asp.net, textbox, controls, findcontrol

I have  many of `TextBox`es in the ASP.NET page that their `ID` starts with certain string like `xyz`(e.g: `xyz1`,`xyz11`,`xyz999`). I know `FindControl` method, but it finds only by complete `ID` of `Control`.

How can I find controls in which their `ID` be like that on page?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can include the `Extension Method` to get all the textboxes on page mentioned in [**this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4092083/1529657) and then can simply filter with the Id you need like this:-

```
var alltextBoxes = this.Page.FindControls<TextBox>(true).Where(x => x.ID.Contains("xyz"));
```

If you want all the Ids which starts with some specific text say `xyz`, then you can also use [String.StartsWith](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/baketfxw%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) since the textbox Id is a string:-

```
.Where(x => x.ID.StartsWith("xyz"));
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to loop recursively inside the page to find the TextBox controls that match your string:

```
List<TextBox> _TextBoxes;

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _TextBoxes = new List<TextBox>();
    FindTextBoxes(Page, "xyz1");
}

private void FindTextBoxes(Control parent, string startsWith)
{ 
    if(parent.GetType()==typeof(TextBox) && parent.ID.StartsWith(startsWith))
    {
        _TextBoxes.Add(parent as TextBox);
    }
    foreach (var c in parent.Controls)
    {
        FindTextBoxes(c, startsWith);
    }
}
```